# How to Resume offline installer creation of Visual Studio 2015 community without redownloading over 12gigs again?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I download the 7GB+ iso for Visual Studio 2015 with Update3 included. I then started to create the offline installer for the dev. machine using vs_community.exe /layout

It finished (said it was done complete and there was over 12GB that it downloaded) but it said it couldn't download the last thing, windows sdk or something like that, maybe I had missed to say yes to a recent firewall pop-up. Anyway so I said ok and then re-ran the vs_communinty.exe /layout

But it keeps giving Setup Engine access is denied error unless I give it a new empty download directory. If I point it to the previous folder, it fails with Setup Engine Access denied, the logs show error 0x80070005

Anyone know how to make the installer to RESUME so one doesn't have to redownload the full 12.5GB again just for the last 500MB still needed?

Also I'm curious if the 7GB+ on the ISO downloaded will be used at all in the install or not, seems strange to download a 7GB+ iso to just throw it away after then running vs_community.exe /layout  which re-downloads everything to some directory for an offline install. When I downloaded the 7GB+ iso, I figured everything needed for an 'offline install' was already inside of it compressed, but obviously that's not so.

Comment: Didn't find solution but I just restarted entire download from scratch, and made sure to say ok to all firewall pop-ups and it finished completely without error and I see it downloaded 24,184,069,692 bytes! So now I'll just delete the old 12.5GB partial download. But some kind of 'resume' would be nice!